# Ubuntu - Destination Host Unreachable Through Router / ARP Requests

Tags: networking, ip, router, arp

Very strange issues on an Ubuntu server running DNS.

Here is the network setup.

There are two class C network ranges.  Let's say they are:

```
 216.107.249.0/24
 216.107.250.0/24
```

Server is assigned an IP in the 216.107.250.0 range.  From the server, no problems pinging anything in the 216.107.250.0 range.

DNS request comes in from a client on the 216.107.249.0 range.  Wireshark shows the request come in.

The server then sends out arp requests saying "Who has 216.107.249.x?"  Obviously no response because it makes no sense why the server is requesting this since it is on a different subnet.

In the `/etc/network/interfaces` folder on the Ubuntu machine, it is set such that:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 216.107.250.2
        network 216.107.250.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 209.107.250.255
        gateway 209.107.250.1
```

So why is the server requesting an ARP for something not on the same subnet instead of passing along the packet to the router?

Anything else that comes into the server is being sent out properly.  So if other DNS queries come in from anywhere across the Internet, they are being responded to properly with the packet going to the router.

Comment: Just added a static route on the server for the subnet to go through the gateway.  Still will not ping anything on that subnet and ARP requests are still being sent.  Command used was ---   route add -net 216.107.249.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 216.107.250.1